# How to string convert to date about "2021/03/03 00:51" in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to change the data in the format of 2020/03/03 00:51 String into date format.

How can i solve it ?

Anyone can help?

Comment: Date is obsolete. Use LocalDateTime.

Comment: LocalDateTime requires Android 8 with API level 26. But as Tenfour04 wrote, if possible use LocalDateTime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to convert string to date.

**This is predefined format**

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Format y-M-d or yyyy-MM-d
    val string = "2017-07-25"
    val date = LocalDate.parse(string, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE)

    println(date)
```

**using pattern formatters**

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.Locale

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val string = "July 25, 2017"

    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
    val date = LocalDate.parse(string, formatter)

    println(date)
}
```

[Refer here for more information](https://www.programiz.com/kotlin-programming/examples/string-date#:%7E:text=Example%202%3A%20Convert%20String%20to%20Date%20using%20pattern%20formatters&text=So%2C%20we%20create%20a%20formatter,and%20get%20the%20LocalDate%20object.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat)

```kotlin
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")

val date = dateFormat.parse("2020/03/04 00:51")
```